# failing to check if username exists in Access using accdb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-web-developer

```
    String user = Request.Form["username"];
    String Path = Server.MapPath("App_Data/Users.accdb");
    String connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" + user + "'";
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    OleDbDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        Response.Write("user exists");
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
        Response.Write("user does not exist");
    conn.Close();
```

The else always happens when even when I enter a value that exists in the data base, with

```
if (myDataReader.Read())
```

I'm using it in my login page and it works to see if the user exists, I just removed the password part from it.

by the way this is the form I'm using to this page

```
<form method="get" action="profile.aspx">
    <input type="text" name = "username" /><input type = "submit" value = "Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Debugging remotely, what does myDataReader contain when you do the query `SELECT * FROM Users`?

Comment: What is the value of the variable `user`? Try to replace the Response.Write with `Response.Write("user:" + user + ": does not exist");`

Comment: some of my forms were with "method = get " and it was the reason for the failure, it's okay now, sorry for misleading you :S

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score -1):

Just curious...

why dont you change your sql to return one value.

```
String sql = string.Format(@" DECLARE @IsExists BIT
                              SET @IsExists = 0x0
                              SELECT @IsExists = 0x1 FROM Users WHERE UserName='{0}'
                              SELECT @IsExists as 'IsExists'
                              ", user);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
bool IsExists = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScaler());
conn.Close();
return IsExists;
```

FYI, i would use User as parameter instead of constructing string like that.

Comment: -1: you _know_ about SQL Injection Attacks, yet you answer by showing how to suffer such an attack.